# How I can close horisontal navigation panels in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-assist

When I edit sources in VS 2017, I see next navigation panels (above the source):

[image]

Some of them could be created by an Visual Assist. How can I close some of them? Where are the settings for displaying these panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For disabling Visual Studio navigation bars: `Tools` → `Options` → `Text Editor` → `All Languages` (or specified language) → `General` and disable `Navigation Bar` check box:

[image]

For disabling Visual Assist navigation bars: `VAssistX`→`Visual Assist Options`→`Display` and disable `Display VA Navigation Bar` check box:

[image]